# Strange form behavior in IntelliJ's UI Designer

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ's UI designer and now I'm stuck as the designer has decided to chop off half of my form.  In the UI Designer pane where it shows the components you have added to your form, I can clearly see all my components as expected.  But in the main editor window where you see the form itself, IntelliJ has decided to [chop off half of it](http://oi54.tinypic.com/9pqmbn.jpg)!

Has anyone seen this behavior before and/or know how to resolve it?  I have tried doing things like invalidating the cache and restarting IntelliJ several times (which worked once but the problem has come back and I can't seem to resolve it again).  I fixed it the one time by restarting IntelliJ and then there was a little anchor to expand the form a little more to reveal the components that were in the white space, but that anchor no longer appears at the bottom of the form to expand.

I am using IntelliJ 9.0.3 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anchors again used to make the form bigger.  You can right click the form and choose "Expand Selection" (CTL+W) and then you can increase the size of the form in the editor.  I'm not sure why it doesn't expand as you add more components automatically but this solution seems to do the trick.